# Is there a quick way to set the alignment of numbers in Number List to "right" instead of the default "left" with python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a numbered list in my document, generated using python-docx.
By default, the numbers in the list are left-aligned, so you get things like this:

```
8. a
9. b
10. c
```

However, I'd like it to look like:

```
 8. a
 9. b 
10. c
```

The periods line up, basically. I can do this in Word by clicking the numbers, going to "Define New Number Format" and setting alignment to "right". So, I'm wondering if there's a built-in way to do this in python-docx (as opposed to editing the xml directly). I've looked at the "List Number" style but I can't find anything to modify to set the alignment of the numbers to "right" (though I can set the paragraph's alignment to "right", but that's not really the same thing). I also tried looking at document.xml to see if I could do it manually but I haven't made much progress there, and I figured it'd be best to ask if there's a simpler way before going down that route.

If this isn't implemented yet, then I'd greatly appreciate any pointers as to how to get started with editing the xml directly to make this work.

Here's the code that generates the numbered list:

```
family_tree = [] #A list of persons
table = doc.add_table(1, 2)
row_index = 0
for person in family_tree:
    person_paragraph = table.cell(row_index,0).paragraphs[0]
    person_paragraph.style = "List Number"

    #Here, I add runs to person_paragraph with information on the person. But this is 100+ lines of code and irrelevant, I think.

    table.add_row()
    row_index += 1
```

I think this is the important part of the XML that's generated by that code snippet:

```
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListNumber"/>
    </w:pPr>
```

And finally, when I set the alignment of the numbers to "right" in Word, then look at the XML again, it changes to:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="008665CD" w:rsidP="00E7633C" w:rsidRDefault="00EF7546">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListNumber"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="0"/>
    <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
```

So, maybe that helps.

I have tried using python-docx to add these tags.

```
tags = doc.element.xpath('//w:p')
rows = len(tags)
for row in range(0,rows):
    tag = tags[row]                    
    tag.set(qn("w:rsidR"), "008665CD") 
    tag.set(qn("w:rsidP"), "00E7633C")
    tag.set(qn("w:rsidRDefault"), "00EF7546")
```

But that doesn't work. Maybe this isn't the snippet of xml that I should be looking at!

Thank you!

Comment: can you include the code that generates the numbered list, as well as the snippet of xml for the number list as you have it in the example.

Comment: Anything is possible in python :)

Comment: Sure, but the full code is 100+ lines and most of it is probably irrelevant. I'll edit the question.

Comment: I've added the code that generates the numbered list, and the snippet of xml for the list that is generated (with numbers left-aligned). Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. I also added the xml snippet that is generated when I manually change the numbers to be right-aligned in Word. So, we can see the differences in the xml between left-aligned and right-aligned. But there might be other differences in other parts of the xml.